# I can only grab the global keywords and not the article keywords

Tags: database

I can only retrieve the global keywords. Is there a way to retrieve the article's keywords?

I am trying to modify the Administrator template. I want to add each article's keywords to the Articles view page located at (Administrator template: html/com_content/articles/default.php).

Thank you.

```
<?php
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $content = $document->getMetaData('keywords');
    echo $content;
    ?>
```

Comment: It's confusing what you are trying to do. Administrator template, each article keywords to the articles view page ... ?

Comment: The page I want to modify can be found at: Administrator Main Menu - > Content - > Articles. This page lists all the articles. I want to display the keywords for each article the same way the Category is listed.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it by accessing the database correctly. Here is the code:

```
<?php
//get metakey by id
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = $item->id;
$db->setQuery("SELECT metakey FROM #__content WHERE id='$id'");
$metakey = $db->loadResult();
echo $metakey;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would look for the possibility of overriding the articles model to add in the query the metakey column and then call `$item->metakey` in the articles view template, instead of generating db queries for each of the loaded articles.

Actually, because this is a sligth modification, I could even consider to simply do it directly on the core model file and have to maintain this with every update - although not the recommended practice, I might be willing to pay the tribute for this.